# JavaScript not responding to checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a page with checkboxes that have string values (A, B, C). I am trying to create an app that builds a string on the screen based on the values of the selected checkboxes, separated by the '+', for example 'A+B+C' or 'A+B', etc.

Yet, my div is not showing when the checkboxes are selected.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var arr = $(".offers:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  $('#displayConcatenatedString').html(arr.join('+'));
</script>

<div id="displayConcatenatedString"></div>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="A" class="offers" />A</label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="B" class="offers" />B</label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="C" class="offers" />C</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Well that code does not magically run when the checkboxes are checked. It runs when it is called. If you need it to run when their state changes, than you need to bind it as an event listener.

Comment: perhaps need to wrap your js in a [jquery.ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler

Comment: @j08691 I do not get any errors, the string is not showing up in the browser when the checkboxes are checked.

Comment: You have no change or click event bound to the checkboxes

Comment: @csum how would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run your code when the state changes. Essentially your code is running once when the page loads, but you want to build your string whenever one of your checkboxes state changes.

The code below will run the code contained in your question every time one of the checkboxes is clicked (you could also use the `change` event).

```
$(".offers").on("click", function(){
  var arr = $(".offers:checked").map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
    }).get();
  $('#displayConcatenatedString').html(arr.join('+'));  
})
```

Also, your script `my_jq.js`, is included in the header of your page, which means it will run prior to any of the HTML being rendered. That means the click handler suggested above will never fire. There are several ways you can handle that. One is to move the script to the bottom of the page.

```
<body>
    ...stuff...
    <script src="my_jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
</body>
```

And/or you can wrap the above script to load when the page is ready.

```
$(function(){
  $(".offers").on("click", function(){
    var arr = $(".offers:checked").map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
      }).get();
    $('#displayConcatenatedString').html(arr.join('+'));  
  })
})
```

Another option would be a handler attached to the document, but this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Yes, I have it working in jsfiddle too, but it is not working when run on the desktop, which is how it is going to be used.

Comment: I changed the js to your code, it did not work on the desktop

Comment: @FeyziBagirov Check the updated answer. Basically your code is running before the checkboxes exist on the page.